# why do i need to use piecewise_construct in map::emplace for single arg constructors of noncopyable objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, std-pair, emplace

The following code will not compile on gcc 4.8.2.
The problem is that this code will attempt to copy construct an `std::pair<int, A>` which can't happen due to `struct A` missing copy and move constructors.

Is gcc failing here or am I missing something?

```
#include <map>
struct A
{
  int bla;
  A(int blub):bla(blub){}
  A(A&&) = delete;
  A(const A&) = delete;
  A& operator=(A&&) = delete;
  A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
};
int main()
{
  std::map<int, A> map;
  map.emplace(1, 2); // doesn't work
  map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::forward_as_tuple(1),
          std::forward_as_tuple(2)
  ); // works like a charm
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like it's not the fault of `map`, but of `pair`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5232a33731cf220

Comment: @dyp See a related question: [std::unordered_map::emplace issue with private/deleted copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808663/stdunordered-mapemplace-issue-with-private-deleted-copy-constructor?rq=1)

Comment: @remyabel Great! It's a dup/related, I came to a similar conclusion as  jogojapan. However, IMHO the problem is `pair`, not `map`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the issue isn't caused by `map::emplace`, but by `pair`'s constructors:

```
#include <map>

struct A
{
    A(int) {}
    A(A&&) = delete;
    A(A const&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    std::pair<int, A> x(1, 4); // error
}
```

This code example doesn't compile, neither with coliru's g++4.8.1 nor with clang++3.5, which are both using libstdc++, as far as I can tell.

The issue is rooted in the fact that although we can construct

```
A t(4);
```

that is, `std::is_constructible<A, int>::value == true`, we cannot *implicitly convert* an `int` to an `A` [conv]/3

> An expression `e` can be *implicitly converted* to a type `T` if and only if the declaration `T t=e;` is well-formed,
>   for some invented temporary variable `t`.

Note the copy-initialization (the `=`). This creates a temporary `A` and initializes `t` from this temporary, [dcl.init]/17. This initialization from a temporary tries to call the deleted move ctor of `A`, which makes the conversion ill-formed.

---

As we cannot convert from an `int` to an `A`, the constructor of `pair` that one would expect to be called *is rejected by SFINAE*. This behaviour is surprising, [N4387 - Improving pair and tuple](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4387.html) analyses and tries to improve the situation, by making the constructor `explicit` instead of rejecting it. N4387 has been voted into C++1z at the Lenexa meeting.

The following describes the C++11 rules.

The constructor I had expected to be called is described in [pairs.pair]/7-9

> ```
> template<class U, class V> constexpr pair(U&& x, V&& y);
> ```
>
> 7    *Requires:* `is_constructible<first_type, U&&>::value` is `true` and
>   `is_constructible<second_type, V&&>::value` is `true`.
>
> 8    *Effects:* The
>   constructor initializes first with `std::forward<U>(x)` and second with
>   `std::forward<V>(y)`.
>
> 9    *Remarks:* If `U` is not implicitly convertible to
>   `first_type` or `V` is not implicitly convertible to `second_type` this
>   constructor shall not participate in overload resolution.

Note the difference between `is_constructible` in the *Requires* section, and "is not implicitly convertible" in the *Remarks* section. The requirements are fulfilled to call this constructor, but it may not participate in overload resolution (= has to be rejected via SFINAE).

Therefore, overload resolution needs to select a "worse match", namely one whose second parameter is a `A const&`. A temporary is created from the `int` argument and bound to this reference, and the reference is used to initialize the `pair` data member (`.second`). The initialization tries to call the deleted copy ctor of `A`, and the construction of the pair is ill-formed.

---

libstdc++ has (as an extension) some nonstandard ctors. In the [latest doxygen](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01514_source.html#l00096) (and in 4.8.2), the constructor of `pair` that I had expected to be called (being surprised by the rules required by the Standard) is:

```
template<class _U1, class _U2,
         class = typename enable_if<__and_<is_convertible<_U1, _T1>,
                                           is_convertible<_U2, _T2>
                                          >::value
                                   >::type>
constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, _U2&& __y)
: first(std::forward<_U1>(__x)), second(std::forward<_U2>(__y)) { }
```

and the one that *is actually* called is the non-standard:

```
// DR 811.
template<class _U1,
         class = typename enable_if<is_convertible<_U1, _T1>::value>::type>
constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, const _T2& __y)
: first(std::forward<_U1>(__x)), second(__y) { }
```

The program is ill-formed according to the Standard, it is **not** merely rejected by this non-standard ctor.

---

As a final remark, here's the specification of `is_constructible` and `is_convertible`.

`is_constructible` [meta.rel]/4

> Given the following function prototype:
>
> ```
> template <class T>
> typename add_rvalue_reference<T>::type create();
> ```
>
> the predicate condition for a template specialization `is_constructible<T, Args...>` shall be satisfied if and only if the following variable definition would be well-formed for some invented variable `t`:
>
> ```
> T t(create<Args>()...);
> ```
>
> [*Note:* These tokens are never interpreted as a function declaration. — *end note*] Access checking is performed as if in a context unrelated to `T` and any of the `Args`. Only the validity of the immediate context of the variable initialization is considered.

`is_convertible` [meta.unary.prop]/6:

> Given the following function prototype:
>
> ```
> template <class T>
> typename add_rvalue_reference<T>::type create();
> ```
>
> the predicate condition for a template specialization `is_convertible<From, To>` shall be satisfied if and
>   only if the return expression in the following code would be well-formed, including any implicit conversions
>   to the return type of the function:
>
> ```
> To test() {
>   return create<From>();
> }
> ```
>
> [*Note:* This requirement gives well defined results for reference types, void types, array types, and function types. — *end note*] Access checking is performed as if in a context unrelated to `To` and `From`. Only
>   the validity of the immediate context of the expression of the *return-statement* (including conversions to
>   the return type) is considered.

---

For your type `A`,

```
A t(create<int>());
```

is well-formed; however

```
A test() {
  return create<int>();
}
```

creates a temporary of type `A` and tries to *move* that into the return-value (copy-initialization). That selects the deleted ctor `A(A&&)` and is therefore ill-formed.

Comment: What a weird issue :(

Comment: You can also try `static_assert(std::is_convertible<int, A>::value, "int is not convertible to A");` and `static_assert(std::is_constructible<A, int>::value, "A is not constructible from an int");` to illustrate the issue.

Comment: thanks, i assumed it was an overload issue of the templated constructors of std::pair. although on the right track your answer cleared everything up. thanks for the amount of detail in your anwser

Comment: @Oliver'ker'Schneider You might consider filing a bug report. To me, it seems to be an oversight to disallow this form of constructing a pair.

Comment: @ker Thanks. Although I think if that nonstandard ctor wasn't there, the ctor taking two `const&` should be used, which would also fail. So I think the issue is rejecting the `U1&&, U2&&` ctor even though that seems like a reasonable choice. I'll also guess that the libstdc++ implementers will "blame" the Standard, but maybe that'll lead to a discussion if `is_convertible` (or the corresponding wording in the Standard) is intended.

Comment: Using `is_convertible` there is intended, as clarified by [N4064](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4064.html) which is very explicit about the use of `is_convertible`, but also improves things in this area to pick a better constructor for non-copyable, non-movable types.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thank you; I found N3680 four months after answering this question. As anticipated, you "blame the Standard" ;) -- I like the ideas of N3680/N4064, was it rejected? (libc++ implements something similar, but I cannot find the spec in recent drafts)

Comment: @dyp, there will be a new revision of N4064 in the next mailing, and it will probably be accepted at the meeting next month. As for blaming the standard, removing the `is_convertible` constraints would break far more important programs than ones that try to emplace immovable objects in maps. The constraints were added to the standard for good reasons, and both libstdc++ and libc++ obey them for good reasons, not just to pedantically follow the standard. I'm not really sure what you expect implementations to do if not follow the standard.

Comment: @JonathanWakely After reading N3680, I understood the reasons why `is_convertible` is used. Please don't take my "blame the Standard" too seriously. Thanks for the info on the status of N4064.