# std::pair: too restrictive constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I stumbled upon a surprising behaviour of the new `std::pair` constructor, that was introduced with C++11. I observed the issue when using `std::pair<int, std::atomic<int>>`, and it occurs, because `std::atomic` is neither copyable nor movable. In the following code, I replace `std::atomic<int>` with `foobar` for simplification.

The following code compiles fine, both with GCC-4.9 and Clang-3.5 (with and without libc++):

```
struct foobar
{
    foobar(int) { } // implicit conversion
    // foobar(const foobar&) = delete;
};

std::pair<int, foobar> p{1, 2};
```

This behaviour is expected. However, when I delete the copy constructor of `foobar`, the compilation fails. It works with *piecewise construct*, but I think that shouldn't be necessary, because of the implicit conversion from `int` to `foobar`. I am referring to the constructor with the following signature:

```
template <typename U, typename V>
pair(U&& u, V&& v);
```

Can you explain, why the pair constructor is so restrictive, and does not allow implicit conversions for noncopyable/nonmovable types?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't get your comment. In my example, both member variables are directly initialized from `int&&`. No copy constructor for _foobar_ or _pair_ involved.

Comment: Hm, I probably got something wrong. I'm investigating.

Comment: So, I tried reproducing this with my self-made pair class and didn't manage. I looked at the error, which points to the GCC implementation and mentions [DR 811](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#811); curiously, the overload is `template <typename U1, typename = [some enable_if]> pair(U1 &&, const T2 &)`, which does end up making a copy (since it constructs a temporary to bind to the second parameter). But it shouldn't!

Comment: I think this is a dup :) let me see... the problem was that the Standard requires `is_convertible` which surprisingly requires movability. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21405674/420683

Comment: @dyp: It's bad that GCC invents an overload that is not specified by the standard, isn't it?

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't think that's the problem. See my (now linked) answer

Comment: What I found weird about the specification in the Standard that it *requires* constructibility and SFINAE-checks for convertability. I wanted to ask about this on the isocpp/Standard discussion list some time ago..

Comment: @nosid *"because of the implicit conversion from `int` to `foobar`"* And that's the problem. `int` is not implicitly convertible to `foobar` in the strict sense, because `foobar f = 5;` is not well-formed.

Comment: @dyp: there's no implicit conversion involved.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Indeed, and that's why I think it's a defect in the Standard.

Comment: @dyp: the standard doesn't have the constructor that g++ invokes here.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes, but it wouldn't work even w/o this ctor. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21407037/420683).

Comment: @dyp: I wonder if it's OK to have those partial template overloads. The standard says that only the full `(U&&, V&&)` overload should exist, if and only if both `U` and `V` are implicitly convertible, not those intermediate forms.

Comment: @dyp: on the contrary, it [works just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1172c5e1a6ff3b5). your answer therefore appears to be **fundamentally incorrect**.

Comment: @KerrekSB Hmm I think if it's `copy_constructible`, then it is also `convertible` (for the same type).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf You're missing the SFINAE checks that are required by the Standard. Let me check this..

Comment: @dyp: But "requires" is different from "shall not participate", isn't it?

Comment: @dyp: Either way, I think it's not a problem: The OP's code *should* fail, and it does. The fact that GCC passes the first argument through a direct initialization rather than a copy does not diminish this.

Comment: @KerrekSB Exactly. The *requires* part says when there's UB, whereas the "shall not participate" mandates a SFINAE-check. It's weird that those two have different requirements for the type.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d9a21ee6d4f732b

Comment: @dyp: that's not [what the standard requires](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22e51fa2d716f89d); it requires constructible, not convertible. so again, your answer elswhere, that you linked to, appears to **fundamentally incorrect**. "fundamentally": the foundations are wrong.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: No, it does require implicit convertibility for the constructor to participate - it's in the "Remarks", not the "Requires". Weirdly enough, the Standard only uses English, not the `std::is_convertible` trait (which is used in the implementation in GCC).

Comment: @KerrekSB: you mean "yes" it does not rquire convertibility. *Oh*. that's an inconsistency in the standard.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The remarks section requires a SFINAE-check for *convertibility*, and I agree that's unintuitive and probably a defect. The *requires* section AFAIK lists when the function has UB.

Comment: Oh dang. I'll update my answer. Is there a defect report?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't think so. I wanted to post that on the isocpp mailing list a long time ago but never got around doing it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Ok, there *is* already a DR + proposed resolution, see my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a defect in the Standard (I didn't found it at first since it's formulated for `tuple`).

https://wg21.link/lwg2051

Further discussion and a proposed resolution (voted into C++1z at Lenexa in May 2015):

https://wg21.link/n4387

---

The underlying problem is that the converting constructors of `pair` and `tuple` check for `is_convertible` which requires an accessible copy/move constructor.

En detail: The converting constructor templates of `std::pair<T1, T2>` and `std::tuple` look like this:

```
template<class U, class V>
constexpr pair(U&&, V&&);
```

But this is too greedy: It produces a hard error when you try to use it with incompatible types, and `std::is_constructible<pair<T1, T2>, U, V>::value` will always be `true` because the declaration of this constructor template can be instantiated for *any* types `U` and `V`. Hence, we need to restrict this constructor template:

```
template<class U, class V,
    enable_if_t<check_that_we_can_construct_from<U, V>::value>
>
constexpr pair(U&& u, V&& v)
    : t1( forward<U>(u) ), t2( forward<V>(v) )
{}
```

Note that the `tx( forward<A>(a) )` can call `explicit` constructors. Because this constructor template of `pair` is **not marked as explicit**, we must restrict it to **not** perform **explicit conversions internally** while initializing its data members. Therefore, we use `is_convertible`:

```
template<class U, class V,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U&&, T1>::value &&
                     std::is_convertible<V&&, T2>::value>
>
constexpr pair(U&& u, V&& v)
    : t1( forward<U>(u) ), t2( forward<V>(v) )
{}
```

In the case of the OP, there is no implicit conversion: the type is noncopyable, and this renders the test that defines *implicit convertibility* ill-formed:

```
// v is any expression of type `int`
foobar f = v; // definition of implicit convertibility
```

This copy-initialization form according to the Standard produces a temporary on the right hand side, initialized with `v`:

```
foobar f = foobar(v);
```

Where the right hand side shall be understood as an implicit conversion (so no `explicit` constructors can be called). However, this requires to copy or move the temporary on the right hand side into `f` (until C++1z, see [p0135r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html)).

To sum up: `int` is not implicitly convertible to `foobar` because of the way implicit convertibility is defined, which requires moveability because RVO is not mandatory. `pair<int, foobar>` cannot be constructed from `{1, 2}` because this `pair` constructor template is not `explicit` and hence requires implicit conversions.

---

A better solution to the `explicit` vs implicit conversion problem as presented in [Improvements on `pair` and `tuple`](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4387.html) is to have `explicit` magic:

> The constructor is `explicit` if and only if `is_convertible<U&&,
>   first_type>::value` is `false` or `is_convertible<V&&, second_type>::value`
>   is `false`.

With this change, we can loosen the restriction of implicit convertibility (`is_convertible`) to "explicit convertibility" (`is_constructible`). Effectively, we get the following constructor template in this case:

```
template<class U, class V,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<U&&, int>::value &&
                     std::is_constructible<V&&, foobar>::value>
>
explicit constexpr pair(U&&, V&&);
```

Which is unrestricted enough to make `std::pair<int, foobar> p{1, 2};` valid.

Comment: Interesting. The document referenced by the second link discusses exactly the problem I have observed. But I don't understand the first link. I see that it is related to the second link, but is it also related to my question?

Comment: @nosid Kind of. `is_convertible` is also `false` for explicit constructors, so it has the same underlying problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate some more about the issue described there, and how it was resolved (it was supposedly resolved recently, so in C++17 this should work I guess.)

Comment: @einpoklum I've elaborated "slightly" ;)

Comment: [N4528](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4528.html) misses this change. It is in [this commit](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/c8347e3f3caa2ecef1b1dd869ce15b9095134a1a). Is it expected?

Comment: @FrankHB I don't know much about editor reports. Maybe it only lists *notable* changes? http://wg21.link/lwg2051 says *"Resolved by the adoption of N4387."* in May 2015...

Comment: This is strange because even the git log (with more minor editorial changes) has been there. Perhaps it was never published in an editor's report just for some occasional reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Testing your code, with the copy constructor deleted, I get

```
[h:\dev\test\0082]
> g++ foo.cpp
In file included from h:\bin\mingw\include\c++\4.8.2\utility:70:0,
                 from foo.cpp:1:
h:\bin\mingw\include\c++\4.8.2\bits\stl_pair.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr std::pair::pair(_U1&&, const _T2&) [with _U1 = int; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _T1 = int; _T2 = foobar]':
foo.cpp:12:34:   required from here
h:\bin\mingw\include\c++\4.8.2\bits\stl_pair.h:134:45: error: use of deleted function 'foobar::foobar(const foobar&)'
  : first(std::forward<_U1>(__x)), second(__y) { }
                                             ^
foo.cpp:6:5: error: declared here
     foobar(const foobar&) = delete;
     ^

[h:\dev\test\0082]
> cl foo.cpp
foo.cpp

[h:\dev\test\0082]
> _
```

The mentioned constructor

```
pair(_U1&&, const _T2&)
```

is not specified by the standard.

---

Addendum: as shown below the code works just fine with only the standard's constructors defined for the pair class:

```
#include <utility>

struct foobar
{
    foobar(int) { } // implicit conversion
    foobar(const foobar&) = delete;
};

namespace bah {
    using std::forward;
    using std::move;

    struct Piecewise_construct_t {};

    template <class T1, class T2>
    struct Pair {
        typedef T1 first_type;
        typedef T2 second_type;
        T1 first;
        T2 second;

        //Pair(const Pair&) = default;
        //Pair(Pair&&) = default;

        /*constexpr*/ Pair(): first(), second() {}

        Pair(const T1& x, const T2& y)
            : first( x ), second( y )
        {}

        template<class U, class V> Pair(U&& x, V&& y)
            : first( forward<U>( x ) ), second( forward<V>( y ) )
        {}

        template<class U, class V> Pair(const Pair<U, V>& p)
            : first( p.first ), second( p.second )
        {}

        template<class U, class V> Pair(Pair<U, V>&& p)
            : first( move( p.first ) ), second( move( p.second ) )
        {}

        //template <class... Args1, class... Args2>
        //Pair(Piecewise_construct_t,
        //tuple<Args1...> first_args, tuple<Args2...> second_args);
        //
        //Pair& operator=(const Pair& p);
        //template<class U, class V> Pair& operator=(const Pair<U, V>& p);
        //Pair& operator=(Pair&& p) noexcept(see below);
        //template<class U, class V> Pair& operator=(Pair<U, V>&& p);
        //void swap(Pair& p) noexcept(see below);
    };
}

auto main()
    -> int
{
    bah::Pair<int, foobar> p{1, 2};
};
```

```
[h:\dev\test\0082]
> g++ bar.cpp

[h:\dev\test\0082]
> _
```

---

**IMPORTANT ERRATA**.
As @dyb points out in comments, while the standard's “requires” clause refers to `std::is_constructible` (the pair's items must be constructible from the arguments), the “remarks” clause, following the resolution of [Defect Report 811](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#811), refers to convertibility:

C++11 §20.3.2/8:
“*Remarks*: If `U` is not implicitly convertible to `first_type` or `V` is not implicitly convertible to `second_type` this constructor shall not participate in overload resolution.”

And so, while this is arguably now a defect in the standard, from a formal point of view the code should not compile.

Comment: Note that the OP used G++ V4.9, not V4.8.2 . 4.9 is closer to C++11 than 4.8, maybe that's the reason why your testing failed on his code.

Comment: @user465139: judging from the question comments the issue with 4.9 is the same. it has introduced a constructor that isn't there in the standard.