# Why does `std::pair<int, movable>` require a [deleted] `const&` copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std

I'm busy testing an implementation of various generic algorithms and I'm using types with minimal support of provided functions. I came across this weird setup when using a `std::pair<T, movable>` with some type `T` (e.g., `int`) and a `movable` type defined like this:

```
struct movable
{
    movable() {}
    movable(movable&&) = default;
    // movable(movable const&) = delete;
    movable(movable&) = delete;
};
```

The idea is have a type which is movable but not copyable. That works great, e.g., with expressions like this:

```
movable m1 = movable();
movable m2 = std::move(m1);
```

However, when trying to use this type as a member of `std::pair<...>` it fails! To make get the code to compile it is necessary to add the `delete`d(!) copy constructor taking a `movable const&` (or have only that version). The copy constructor taking a non-`const` reference is insufficient:

```
#include <utility>
auto f() -> std::pair<int, movable> {
    return std::pair<int, movable>(int(), movable());
}
```

What is going on here? Is `std::pair<...>` overspecified by mandating that `std::pair(std::pair const&)` is `= default`ed?

The problem seems to be down to the specification of `std::pair`'s copy constructor (in 20.3.2 [pairs.pair] synopsis):

> ```
>  namespace std {
>      template <class T1, class T2>
>      struct pair {
>          ...
>          pair(const pair&) = default;
>          ...
>      };
>  }
> ```

A quick check with my implementation implies that the obvious implementation copying the two members does *not* require the `const&` version of the `movable` copy constructor. That is, the offensive part is the `= default` on `pair`'s copy constructor!

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::pair: too restrictive constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723744/stdpair-too-restrictive-constructor)

Comment: @Borgleader: I'd agree that it is related but this question doesn't address the problem of the `= default` being mandated being a problem! ... or, for that matter, why using `= default` actually causes this problem. The proposed resolution to the issue also leaves the offensive `pair(pair const&) = default` in place.

Comment: @Dietmar: My reading of that question/answer suggested that `=default` was not a problem at all. It should not be instantiated unless used.

Comment: Oh.. is it that time of the year again, when you start posting interesting questions? :D

Comment: It seems not to have been cited yet: [dcl.fct.def.default]/1.2 says why the defaulted copy-ctor of `pair` is illegal - and I interpret it as saying that *its declaration is ill-formed*, so no instantiation is required to make the program ill-formed.

Comment: @dyp: yes, carefully rereading this clauses implies, indeed, that it causes the defaulted copy constructor of `std::pair` to become ill-formed if there is a `= delete`d copy constructor taking a non-`const` reference for one of the members as it _adds_ rather than _removes_ a cv-qualifier. It seems `std::pair`'s copy constructor is over-specified in this case! Seems I need to raise an LWG issue.

Comment: Do you happen to know *why* the assignment-operators are declared explicitly? If that was not necessary, it seems as if the copy ctor could just be left implicitly declared (and the issue should disappear).

Comment: @dyp: The assignment operators are explicitly defined to deal with the `noexcept(...)` qualification. I doubt that these will be dropped.

Comment: As far as I understand the specification in [except.spec]/16, an implicitly-declared move assignment-operator should have the same exception-specification as the one required for `std::pair` ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0356f76a9f1819f)). The effects of this implicitly defined operator also match (as far as I can see) the required effects of `std::pair`'s move op. Both libc++ and libstdc++ implement the move assignment-op manually, though (why?).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::pair` copy constructor is declared as follows:

```
pair(const pair&) = default;
```

By declaring this copy constructor for `movable`:

```
movable(movable&) = delete;
```

you inhibit implicit creation of `movable(const movable&)` (so it's not even deleted, there's just no such constructor), thus this is the only copy constructor you have. But `std::pair` copy constructor requires a copy constructor of its members to take const reference, so you get compile error.

If you add this:

```
movable(movable const&) = delete;
```

or (better) just remove `movable(movable&) = delete;` declaration, you now have the `movable(movable const&)` constructor, and because it's deleted, the `std::pair` copy constructor also becomes deleted.

**Update**: Let's consider a simpler example demonstrating the same issue. This doesn't compile:

```
template <typename T>
struct holder {
    T t;
    // will compile if you comment the next line
    holder(holder const&) = default;
    // adding or removing move constructor changes nothing WRT compile errors
    // holder(holder&&) = default;
};

struct movable {
    movable() {}
    movable(movable&&) = default;
    // will also compile if you uncomment the next line
    //movable(movable const&) = delete;
    movable(movable&) = delete;
};

holder<movable> h{movable()};
```

It will compile if you comment the copy constructor of `holder`, because this is how implicit copy constructor generation works (`[class.copy]/8`:

> The implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class X will have the form
>
> `X::X(const X&)`
>
> if each potentially constructed subobject of a class type `M` (or array thereof) has a copy constructor whose first parameter is of type `const M&` or `const volatile M&`. Otherwise, the implicitly-declared copy constructor will have the form
>
> `X::X(X&)`

That is, when you comment out the declaration `holder(holder const&) = default;` the implicitly declared copy constructor of `holder` will have the form `holder(holder&)`. But if you don't, `T`'s copy constructor has take `const T&` (or `const volatile T&`)  because this is what will be called in memberwise copy procedure described in `[class.copy]/15`.

And if `holder` has a move constructor, it's even easier - if you comment out `holder(holder const&) = default;`, the implicitly declared copy constructor of `holder` will be just deleted.

Comment: Well, I understand things this far - except that my code obviously never actually copies the pair! It only moves the pair. ... as is shown by the code compiling when adding a `= delete`d copy constructor causing it to compile. Also, defining `std::pair`'s copy constructor with the obvious implementation instead of using `=default` make the code compile!

Comment: @DietmarKühl yes, but the compiler has to instantiate `std::pair` copy constructor anyway (and if it becomes deleted it's ok, but not when it can't compile)

Comment: Why does it need to do so? Implementing `pair`'s copy constructor using the obvious approach removes this need. Shouldn't the `= default` version behave the same?

Comment: Well, your `holder` is clearly not move-constructible as it declares a copy constructor thereby inhibiting an automatically created move constructor but also doesn't declare a move construct. `std::pair` defines a move constructor (it is also `= default`ed). I still don't want to copy my object but only move it.

Comment: The issue seems to be what @dyp pointed out: the declaration of defaulted constructor is ill-formed if it differs from the one which would be implicitly declared (except for adding `const`), independent on whether it is used or not.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I think the real issue is `movable` having the constructor `movable(movable&)` (even deleted). It doesn't make any sense to add it.

Comment: Well, for move-only types it makes sense to explicitly disable copy construction. Sure, it _could_ be done using `movable(movable const&)` but since this constructor isn't to be used either variation _should_ work. I can clearly fix the issue for _my_ code but creating libraries I'd like to be friendly to users who use the library. If `std::pair` wouldn't be defined to have an `= default`ed copy constructor, both versions would work (and a standard library defaulting the copy constructor would be wrong).