# Why do we need piecewise_construct in map emplace in C++20?

Tags: c++, sfinae, c++20, c++-concepts

This it theoretical question about potential overload of std::map emplace function that detects that it has been passed 2 tuples, not a question if this functionality exists in C++20.

From what I saw in previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405674/why-do-i-need-to-use-piecewise-construct-in-mapemplace-for-single-arg-construc) map emplace is "victim" of std::pair's problems.

So that got me wondering why is there no concepts/SFINAE overload of map emplace that is active only when we pass 2 tuples to emplace (and key/value are constructible from respective tuples).

Reasons I thought of:

- weirdo classes that take std::tuple as argument to constructor(potentially also they have ctor with that tuple's types expanded into normal arguments)
- nobody thought it was worthwhile investing time in saving a bit of typing by solving one specific problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> weirdo classes that take std::tuple as argument to constructor

Yes, exactly.

If you decided that `m.emplace(x, y)` *automatically* did piecewise_construct functionality for tuples `x` and `y`, then it would be impossible for me to emplace construct this:

```
struct Key { Key(std::tuple<int, int>); bool operator<(Key const&) const; };
struct Value { Value(std::tuple<char>); };
map<Key, Value> m;
m.emplace(std::tuple(1, 2), std::tuple('3'));
```

I need to provide `tuple`s for both types, but instead I'd *always* get two `int`s for `Key` and a `char` for `Value` and that doesn't work. I would necessarily have to either add an extra constructor for `Key` or just not do any emplacing.

Now, if you follow up and say, okay, `m.emplace(x, y)` will automatically do `piecewise_construct` if `x` and `y` are tuples *and also* the piecewise construction is actually valid... then , first, that's getting fairly complicated. But also, what if both constructions are valid?

```
struct Key2 {
    Key2(std::tuple<int, int>);
    Key2(int, int);
    bool operator<(Key2 const&) const;
};
map<Key2, Value> m2;
m2.emplace(std::tuple(1, 2), std::tuple('3'));
```

Now this always uses the `(int, int)` constructor. Is that what the user intended here?

Basically, having them separate means the user can do what they need and there's no ambiguity.

Comment: Great answer, but for the last part: standard could say that STL needs to static assert on ambiguity and warn user to use piecwise tag, but tbh I do not know if standard ever does this(tell the STL to detect weird use cases and notify users).

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Keep in mind that "weirdo classes" includes `std::tuple`. `Key2` behaves exactly like `std::tuple<int, int>` here.