# std::set::emplace complaining about deleted copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

Suppose I have the following class in a header file:

```
//Minimized example to show the issue
class Foo    
{
public:
    Foo(); //implemented in .cpp
    Foo(Foo const &foo) = delete;
    Foo(Foo &&foo); //implemented in .cpp
private:
    //member variables
}
```

I wrote a function that takes in `Foo &&` as a parameter and emplaces
it to a set. Which looks like this:

```
void bar(Foo &&foo)
{
    //std::set<Foo> mySet defined elsewhere
    mySet.emplace(foo); //Compiler complains using deleted copy ctor
}
```

The compiler would complain my code was using the `=delete`'d copy ctor, but
if I change the function body to:

```
mySet.emplace(std::move(foo));
```

everything becomes fine.

Why does calling `std::move` on foo solve this problem?

I'm using Windows 10 and VS 2017.

I found [std::unordered_map::emplace issue with private/deleted copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808663/stdunordered-mapemplace-issue-with-private-deleted-copy-constructor) but that was using gcc and might be outdated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And a copy of `foo` becomes type `Foo &`...?

Comment: re-reading, I realize it's not clear at all because I had not looked at your definition of Foo, so I'll try to rephrase: within `bar`, `foo` is an lvalue, and is not eligible for `Foo(Foo&&)`. So the compiler picks the other and complains it's deleted.

Comment: @spectras so you are saying with `bar`, `foo` is an lvalue, and an rvalue reference?

Comment: @user3291342 the entity `foo` is an rvalue reference, but the expression `foo` is an lvalue of type `Foo`